# Are there any mavoi-chatzer structures in active use?

Tags: eruv-chatzerot, maseches-eruvin

A lot of Eiruvin assumes that people live in houses, which open into a walled courtyards (chatzer), with a few courtyards opening into a walled street (mavoi).  An eruv chatzeiros allows carrying from the houses into the courtyard, and a shituf mevo'os allows carrying from the courtyards into the mavoi.

Most contemporary eiruvin mimic a chatzer by building a wall around a big area, with no mavoi in the picture and no need for a shituf mevo'os.

Are any mevo'os left anywhere in the world where Jews live and make eruvei chatzeiros and shitufei mevo'os as described in Eiruvin?  Or were there recently (maybe in Arab countries)?

Comment: Isn't that what regular apartment buildings are?

Comment: @DoubleAA You mean each floor is a chatzer and the stairs are a mavoi?  Or the building is the chatzer and outside is a mavoi, assuming it's enclosed by a colloquial "eruv"?  Either way, if people actually make an eruv and shituf as in Eiruvin that's an answer.  I've never heard of it being done.  But I also live in a house so maybe I wouldn't know.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_שפז_א people don't do both today generally

Comment: @DoubleAA it seems from the end of https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Eruvin.6.6 that an apartment building is not its own chatzer.  Otherwise it would say shituf instead of eruv at least in the חדרים או עליות case.  The Rama you brought probably means the answer is no for Ashkenazim but do you know if Sefardim follow that practice too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Yerushalayim Ir HaKodesh.  The Old City has a few, as well as on Rechov Strauss, towards Mea Shearim (as of 2014).  While you're right that this isn't so much the case in modern cities, the Gemara does talk in specific cases to highlight principles and these should be applied in any given scenario.

Comment: Thank you, there's just one piece of the question missing - do you know if anyone (Sefardim probably because of the Rama DoubleAA quoted in a comment to the question) makes eruvei chatzeiros and shitufei mevo'os as described in Eiruvin?

Comment: Yes, I've done it a few times myself.  Usually, the Rav of a community makes it, but in any event In my apartment block we did it, usually erev Pesach (with Matzos).

Comment: both eiruvei chatzeiros and shitufei mevo'os separately?

Comment: No, just eiruv chatzeiros, Shitufei Mavoi was not relevant to me, but if there are frum Jews in the old city, I would assume it falls under Rav Nevensal (the Rav of the Old City) to do it.

Comment: Then this doesn't answer the question, unless someone tells us that R' Nevensal or somebody else actually does it rather than including everything in one eruv as most cities do.

Comment: You asked: "Are any mevo'os left anywhere in the world where Jews live and make eruvei chatzeiros and shitufei mevo'os as described in Eiruvin?" I answered you and said that there are places in Yerushalayim where there are mavo'os. I also told you that Apartment buildings make eiruvei chatzeiros.  If people living in these places are frum and would consult a Rav, he would tell them to do shitufei Mevo'os and eiruvei Chatzeiros.  There is no question that it would be a kulah to rely on Yerushalayim as a whole (on Rechov Strauss).

Comment: As regards the Old City I'm not familiar with Rav Nebensal's psak on the walls of the Old City. If you like I can find out out if people living in the Old City actually do this.

Comment: The Zilberman's put up lechi's at the entrances to a bunch of courtyards in the Old City years ago.